# Why I got The relevant error-causing widget was: Scaffold?

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, widget, scaffold

Hello everyone I want to dispaly some informations inside scaffold but I got
The relevant error-causing widget was: Scaffold.
Even when I remove it I still got errors:

this is the code :

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: ExpansionTile(
            title: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  widget.model.name,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                ),
                Text(
                  widget.model.id.toString(),
                  style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                )
              ],
            ),
            leading: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
                //  children: [
                // Text(widget.model.mtu.toString()),
                children: <Widget>[
                  StreamBuilder(
                    stream: widget.model.mtu,
                    initialData: 0,
                    builder: (c, snapshot) => ListTile(
                      title: const Text('MTU Size'),
                      subtitle: Text('${snapshot.data} bytes'),
                    ),
                    // ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            trailing: TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  buttonText = 'Connecting...';
                });
                widget.viewModel.establishConnectAndEnableNotify(widget.model);
              },
              child: Text(
                buttonText,
                style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.blue),
              ).tr(),
            )));
  }
}
```

I would be very thankful if you can help me

Comment: I couldn't reproduce the error, I had to exclude the StreamBuilder because of missing stream-data.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurring because of using `ListTile`, it is trying to get infinite width. You can wrap it with SizedBox and provide width. Using `LayoutBuilder` on top level will be better to get the parent widget width.

```dart
return Scaffold(
    body: LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (_, constraints) => ExpansionTile(
      title: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[],
      ),
      leading: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          //  children: [
          // Text(widget.model.mtu.toString()),
          children: <Widget>[
            StreamBuilder(
              // stream: "widget.model.mtu",
              initialData: 0,
              builder: (c, snapshot) => SizedBox(
                width:
                    constraints.maxWidth * .2, //depend on you or hard-coded value
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(' w ${constraints.maxWidth}'),
                  subtitle: Text('${snapshot.data} bytes'),
                ),
              ),
              // ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Also, I think you don't want to have `SingleChildScrollView` on `leading`, maybe you like to use it on `children`

Comment: I got another exception Another exception was thrown: A RenderFlex overflowed by Infinity pixels on the bottom.

Comment: While using `SingleChildScrollView`?